# Unzipping a file with special characters in filenames from API24 upward

Tags: android, unzip

I have an app that unzipps a zipfile, that contains a lot of files with different names. Some files in the Zipfile have special characters.

Unzipping worked for all devices using API 23 and less so far.

With API 24 and API 25 it unzipps some files, but I get an Zip malformed error when it comes to unzip a specific file (name) -> battle of chÔteau_thierry (1814).jpa (There is a special Character Ô in it)

How can I unzip files with special characters, without manipulating the zip. I mean it worked already for API's less then 24.

Can someone help me ?

```
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(zipname);
        Enumeration enumeration = zipFile.entries();

        while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {

            ZipEntry zipEntry = null;
            zipEntry = (ZipEntry) enumeration.nextElement();  <----- Craches, when it comes to the file : battle of chÔteau_thierry (1814).jpa
            String sName = zipEntry.getName();
}
```

*** Update ***

Link to the zipfile:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzTzuiIaUzqkd3loR2dPdW03T28/view?usp=sharing

You have to download the file locally, because google drive converts the filenames implicitely. (battle of chateau_thierry (1814).jpa, french) You only see the character Ô in a local zipfile.

Stacktrace, which I get only for API 24 & 25 devices:

```
Hint : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED[1]
at java.util.zip.ZipCoder.toString(ZipCoder.java:65)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getZipEntry(ZipFile.java:548)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.-wrap2(ZipFile.java)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.nextElement(ZipFile.java:530)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.nextElement(ZipFile.java:508)
at solveraapps.chronicbrowser.ChronicBrowser.unzipImages(ChronicBrowser.java:8011)
at solveraapps.chronicbrowser.ChronicBrowser$16.run(ChronicBrowser.java:8442)
```

Comment: What is the Java stack trace of the crash? Can you upload a sample ZIP file that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. I just updated the question with reference to the zipfile and the stacktrace. Also added some code, so it could be pasted to reproduce. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is no file named `chÔteau.jpg` in that ZIP archive.

Comment: I see the problem. You have to download the zip file locally. Only then you will see a file called "battle of chÔteau_thierry (1814).jpa" in the archive. I have just tested it. Google Drive does a implicit conversion it seems.

Comment: I had downloaded it locally before posting my previous comment. I see a `ba/` directory. In there, the closest match is `battle of chтteau_thierry (1814).jpa`.

Comment: right, thats the file. obviously its name differs depending on the viewer ?. The file is also in a subfolder "ba", thats right. the problematic character will be "т"

Comment: I can reproduce the problem, but it also fails for me on API Level 23, with `Caused by: java.io.UTFDataFormatException: bad second or third byte at 16`. And the comments in `ZipCoder` (the class throwing the exception in your stack trace) indicate that it only supports UTF-8 filenames. Are you sure that this ZIP archive is using UTF-8 encoding for the filenames?

Comment: I retested with Emulators running with API 19,23,25 again. It works for me with 19 and 23. On 23 I debugged and I can see the Filename with the special character. On 25 I don't get to the name, because it throws the mentoined error. I have no other stacktrace then the one mentoined. (No different Errors). Strange, that you get a different error. You asked about UTF-8 support. I don't know how I could influence this. I have just zipped the file.

Comment: FWIW, my API Level 23 test was on a Nexus 5.

Comment: This file is stored on a server and downloaded and unzipped I guess several 100000 times without problems. Now comes API24,25 and its unable to unzip anymore. I can't believe it :-(

Answer (score 2):

I happely solved it now and I hope I can help the upvoter too ?

The API has changed from Nougat regarding the ZipFile. From 24 upward you can specify a CharSet when constructing a ZipFile :

```
ZipFile(String name, Charset charset) // Charset only when >=24
```

In the Docu it sais:

```
The UTF-8 charset is used to decode the entry names and comments
```

So my coding solution is to set the correct Characterset to "ISO-8859-1":

```
@TargetApi(24)
public void myUnzipper(){

            ZipFile zipFile = null;
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N){ // N for Nougat
                zipFile = new ZipFile(zipname,Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
            }else{
                zipFile = new ZipFile(zipname);
            }

            while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {

                ZipEntry zipEntry = null;
                zipEntry = (ZipEntry) enumeration.nextElement();  <----- Craches, when it comes to the file : battle of chÔteau_thierry (1814).jpa
                String sName = zipEntry.getName();
            }

}
```